# How do I set MySQL temporarily to read-only through the command line?

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, readonly

I'm creating a bash script which, among other things, gathers some data from a MySQL database. My MySQL user has write privileges, but for safety reasons I would like to temporarily set it to a read only state. Is it possible to do this from a command line?

Comment: Change user, perhaps?

Comment: There's a similar question (with an answer) at dba.s.c: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74670/revoke-write-privileges-vs-setting-database-to-readonly

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To answer your original question, you can put your whole database to read only mode by this commands:

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SET GLOBAL read_only = 1;
```

and back to normal mode with:

```
SET GLOBAL read_only = 0;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Beware that this is an operation which will have deep impact on the behavior of the database. So before executing this, read the available documentation to the commands above. A much more common way is to revoke DML privileges from the specific user and afterwards grant them back.

Comment: Best answer, if the OP really wants to set the whole database in read-only mode. Title and actual question are confusing here. Anyway, +1 for simplest solution.

Comment: To save others some searching, here's what I read before playing with these: [read_only global](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only) (includes mention of `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;`) and [using these for backups](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/replication-solutions-backups-read-only.html).

Comment: After i did the above method, my database still in Read+Write mode only.

Answer (score 27):

If you're using MySQL 5.6 or newer and InnoDB, you can make a session read-only.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html

"READ ONLY" also offers a modest [performance benefit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332824/does-mysql-innodb-engine-run-any-performance-optimization-for-read-only-transact).

Comment: That should be the accepted answer for this question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if the user right now has all privileges first, you need to revoke it

```
$>mysql -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS --execute="REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'YOUR_USER';"
```

After that you give him, the select permission

```
$>mysql -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS --execute="GRANT SELECT ON 'YOUR_DATABASE'@.* TO 'YOUR_USER'@'%';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

Do your stuff and after that grant privileges again to the user

```
$>mysql -u DB_USER -pDB_PASS --execute="GRANT ALL ON 'YOUR_DATABASE'@.* TO 'YOUR_USER'@'%';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

And that's all folks

NOTE: Review for quotation, perhaps i forgot something