# Table In Use - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a serious issue with an 'in use' table.

An admin for the site attempted  to back up the database with mysqldumper but an important table remains in use. The entire site is down.

Have tried to repair the table from CPanel and PHPMyAdmin but no luck. The same file not found error is returned.

The site is ran through rented Web host so shell might be out of the question.

Have tried just about everything without luck.

I appreciate that it's not about to go on, any ideas on this one please?

Comment: Have you tried contacting your web hosting provider for assistance in restarting the MySQL server?

Comment: Didn't think of that, but could be worth a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Let us know how that turns out.

Comment: Right. I don't think this will be possible. Web host doesn't want to do it apparently. Really stuck for ideas. Usually in the post, simply repairing the table worked but this one doesn't want to!

Comment: SQL has been restarted, but no change.

Comment: Can you set the offending table to single_user or readonly mode?  (Not sure if that's possible in mysql but thats usually what we have to do in the 2012 arena) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401120/how-do-i-set-mysql-temporarily-to-read-only-through-the-command-line

Comment: I think you should post this question on at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in the Database directory:

recover --safe-recover --force [Table Name]

Depending on table size, this can take a long time.  On large tables it's much faster to restart the MySql service.  That sometimes works, though it did not work for the OP.

(Yes, I know it's a year late.  Traffic was terrible.)