# Is there an easy way to put application into a “Read Only” mode?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a to reboot the production web server and want to restrict updates for the duration of the scheduled outage. During this time the users could still view data.

Is there an easy way to tell Cake to lock down the update pages?

I had thought I could add a global variable in the config file which all the update pages check.  If it is set they disable the page.

Maybe it could be done in the controllers. If you go to an add/edit/delete page set a flash message and redirect to index.

I am using MySQL so I could put it into read-only but then the users would get errors.

Comment: There's a way you can switch read-only mode on your database, if you're using MySQL you'll want to discuss this with your database administrator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401120/how-do-i-set-mysql-temporarily-to-read-only-through-the-command-line

Comment: "closed for maintenance come back in an hour" seems simpler

Comment: I think I will update the controllers so that add/edit/delete are redirected back to index and a flash message displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cakephp 1.3

core.php

```
<?php
...
// Offline mode
Configure::write( 'SiteSettings.site_status', 'Online' );
Configure::write( 'SiteSettings.site_offline_url', '/offline' );
...
?>
```

app_controller.php

```
<?php
...
function beforeFilter()
{
    ...
    // Offline mode
    if( ( Configure::read( 'SiteSettings.site_status' ) == 'Offline' ) and ( $this->here != Configure::read( 'SiteSettings.site_offline_url' ) ) )
    {
        $this->redirect( Configure::read( 'SiteSettings.site_offline_url' ) );
    }
    ...
}
...
?>
```

views/pages/offline.php

```
<div>Whatever HTML you want for "offline mode"</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is the sort of think I had in mind but I would redirect to index so they can still view the data.