# How to safely expose SQL in an API with Ruby?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, database, api

I need to design an API that's based in Ruby.  One feature I would like to include is the ability to use SQL(apparently Salesforce has something like this).  Obviously, this could be very dangerous, though it would be fine if I could disallow writes.

How should I go about accomplishing this?  And for curiosity's sake, what's a good way of restricting SQL queries to reads?  I'm using MySQL, by the way, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to create an SQL user without write access.  Then have your API access the database using the restricted user's credentials. See the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401120/how-do-i-set-mysql-temporarily-to-read-only-through-the-command-line) for the details.

And yes, using MySQL matters.  There is no concept of SQL users/accounts in sqlite for example.