# Does MySQL InnoDB engine run any performance optimization for read-only transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

According to the reference documentation the READ ONLY transaction flag may hint the storage engines for running some optimizations.

SET SESSION TRANSACTION READ ONLY;

> If the transaction access mode is set to READ ONLY, changes to tables
>   are prohibited. This may enable storage engines to make performance
>   improvements that are possible when writes are not permitted.

Does the InnoDB engine run such optimizations for read-only transactions?

Comment: See [8.5.3 Optimizing InnoDB Read-Only Transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-performance-ro-txn.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax was important for MySQL 5.6, where creating a `READ ONLY` transaction saved InnoDB from setting up a number of structures internally.

In MySQL 5.7, the optimization was extended so that all transactions would start out `READ ONLY` and then convert to `READ_WRITE` as required.  This is described further in [this blog post](https://mysqlserverteam.com/transaction-life-cycle-improvements-in-5-7-3/).